# How do I remove a specific event callback from an HTML element with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have an element in a webpage which has several callbacks on it

```
// First callback
$("#element").click(fn1);

// Second callback
$("#element").click(fn2);

// Definitions
function fn1(){console.log("1");}
function fn2(){console.log("2");}
```

Is there a way to remove only fn2 from the list of callbacks triggered by jQuery.
I know I could add an 'if' inside the function and some global variable, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second parameter in the [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) function specifies the handler to unbind.

```
$("#element").unbind("click", fn2);
```

**Working Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/k73Nx/

Comment: Depends what version. If it's anything new (1.7+) at all then this answer is not good. Use $('#element').off('click');

Comment: @Adam, `unbind()` is neither deprecated nor removed (as `live()` is for instance). You can still use it as an equivalent to `off()`.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - agreed, however straight from the jQuery docs themselves: (As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() and .off() methods are preferred to attach and remove event handlers on elements.) - makes it sound like unbind and bind will be deprecated soon enough. Why not heed the warning?

Comment: @Adam, that depends. For now, `bind()` and `unbind()` can be used with all versions of jQuery, whereas `on()` and `off()` are only supported in 1.7+. So using the former might be a safer bet, depending on the releases you target.

Answer (score 4):

Interesting that nobody mentioned namespaces yet. Is there a reason for that?

When attaching your event, you can namespace it. Instead of `$(elem).on('click', fn)` you would add a namespace to the click event. `$(elem).on('click.namespaced', fn)`

When unbindung, you can then unbind that exact event, using the namespace as well.
`$(elem).off('click.namespaced')`

This is most practical when you're defining your event function inline.

One more thing you can do with namespaces is to unbind all event types within a namespae with just a single call: `$(elem).off('.namespaced')`

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with your syntax here, other answers are very loose with theirs.

If you use:

```
$('#element').on('click',function() {
 //callback code
});
```

Then you must use:

```
$('#element').off('click');
```

You **cannot** use

```
$('body').off('click','#element',function() { });
```

or

```
$(document).off('click','#element',function() { });
```

because you originally bound your event to #element, not to document or body.

Answer (score 0):

Use unbind: http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

Example:

```
$(document).unbind('click', fn2);
```

Answer (score 0):

use .off

```
 $("#element").off("click",fn2);
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/y93nK/)

Comment: This removes an event handler attached to the body element that handles clicks on #element - in the question, the poster added the click event to the element itself so this will not work.

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle? I couldn't get off to work and I'm wondering if its because it wasn't bound with `on`

Comment: fiddle is there.. check it out